# Process a list containing multi dimensional JSON without using any nested for loops

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have written below code to process the json_list mention below. But it has nested loops and am not so satisfied. I am looking to fetch rateAmounts, roomTypeList in each ratePlanSchedule and ratePlanMasterInfo/ratePlanBasedOnRates/dynamicBaseRate and ratePlanCode.

Json List :

```
[
            {
                "ratePlanScheduleList": {
                    "ratePlanSchedule": [
                        {
                            "ratePlanScheduleId": {
                                "id": "3758813",
                                "type": "RateSetId"
                            },
                            "ratePlanScheduleDetail": {
                                "rateAmounts": {
                                    "onePersonRate": 100,
                                    "twoPersonRate": 100,
                                    "overrideFloorAmount": False
                                },
                                "roomTypeList": [
                                    "KKABI"
                                ],
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "ratePlanScheduleId": {
                                "id": "4247415",
                                "type": "RateSetId"
                            },
                            "ratePlanScheduleDetail": {
                                "rateAmounts": {
                                    "onePersonRate": 100,
                                    "twoPersonRate": 100,
                                    "threePersonRate": 100,
                                    "fourPersonRate": 100,
                                    "fivePersonRate": 100,
                                    "extraPersonRate": 1,
                                    "extraChildRate": 1,
                                    "overrideFloorAmount": False
                                },
                                "roomTypeList": [
                                    "KAAE",
                                    "KKABI",
                                    "KNSM",
                                    "QQNSM",
                                    "QQQELJ",
                                    "SKBLW",
                                    "SKKABM",
                                    "SKTBAR"
                                ],
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "ratePlanScheduleId": {
                                "id": "4255775",
                                "type": "RateSetId"
                            },
                            "ratePlanScheduleDetail": {
                                "rateAmounts": {
                                    "onePersonRate": 90,
                                    "twoPersonRate": 100,
                                    "threePersonRate": 110,
                                    "fourPersonRate": 120,
                                    "fivePersonRate": 125,
                                    "overrideFloorAmount": False
                                },
                                "roomTypeList": [
                                    "QQNSM",
                                    "QQQELJ"
                                ],
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "ratePlanCode": "3A"
                },
                "ratePlanMasterInfo": {
                    "ratePlanBasedOnRates": [
                        {
                            "dynamicBaseRate": {
                                "dynamicBasedOnRatePlan": "RACK",
                                "dynamicBaseAmount": -10,
                                "flatOrPercentage": "PCT",
                                "rounding": "N",
                                "compareWithRateSchedules": True
                            },
                            "basedOnRatePlanType": "DynamicBaseRate"
                        }
                    ],
                },
            
            }
            ]
```

I have written below code to process the above JSON :

```
for i in range(0, len(ratePlanSchedule_list)):    
                    ratePlanSchedule_sub_list = ratePlanSchedule_list[i]["ratePlanScheduleList"]"ratePlanSchedule"]
                    
                    ratePlanCode = ratePlanSchedule_list[i]["ratePlanScheduleList"]["ratePlanCode"]
                    
                    ratePlanBasedOnRates = ratePlanSchedule_list[i]['ratePlanMasterInfo']['ratePlanBasedOnRates']
                    
                    for j in range(0, len(ratePlanSchedule_sub_list)):
                        roomTypeList = ratePlanSchedule_sub_list[j]['ratePlanScheduleDetail']["roomTypeList"]
                        
                        
                        rateAmounts = ratePlanSchedule_sub_list[j]['ratePlanScheduleDetail']['rateAmounts']
                        
                        for k in range(0, len(ratePlanBasedOnRates)):
                           
                                dynamicBaseAmount = ratePlanBasedOnRates[k]['dynamicBaseRate']['dynamicBaseAmount']
                                flatOrPercentage = ratePlanBasedOnRates[k]['dynamicBaseRate']['flatOrPercentage']
```

Comment: If you're looking for code review, there's a separate site for that: [codereview.se]

Comment: what is `json_list` vs `ratePlanSchedule_list`?

Comment: You have a bunch of print statements, but give the input above, what exactly do you want as output?

Comment: In a nutshell I need to process the above Json with at most NLogN time complexity. Which I am unable to do so on the code I  have written . I need to inputs/help to reduce the time complexity which is N*N*N now.